# Is there a single word to mean "rate of procrastination"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Take the following contrived sentence:

> Our staff's productivity has doubled since we upgraded their computers.

And now this one:

> Our staff's *[rate of procrastination]* has doubled since we gave them new smart phones.

**Is there a single word to fit within the italicised section of the second sentence?**

As you can see I initially was looking for some sort of form of the word "procrastinate", but "procrastination" doesn't sound like it fits properly on its own (does it?), and I don't think the word has a valid form  that is equivalent to "productivity", by which I mean that: your *productivity* is a measure how much you *produce*, while *[what?]* is a measure of how much you *procrastinate*.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm completely out of touch with tagging here, so someone please correct my stab in the dark tagging effort as necessary.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to answer this question but I have to put it off till tomorrow.

Comment: @Robusto: I propose *robustivity*, then.

Comment: I think ADHD would be appropiate. ;-)

Comment: Pity, *woolgatherance* doesn't seem to exist. Perhaps it's time someone got around to fixing that. "Since we gave our staff new smart phones, they have experieced a striking dearth of [round tuits](https://www.zazzle.com/a_round_tuit_classic_round_sticker-217332166022116957)."

Comment: Let me think about it a bit.  And consult the web.  And check Facebook while I'm at it.

Comment: I'd vote for woolgathering. The question is for the *Rate* of procrastination. By definition such a rate is *Eternal* as in *tomorrow plus one*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you need a word that includes "rate of"; you can just use *procrastination*.

> Our staff's procrastination has doubled since we gave them new smart phones.

That said, this might work better with a slight rephrase:

> Procrastination has doubled since we gave the staff new smart phones.

You can even rephrase the productivity sentence to match:

> Productivity has doubled since we upgraded the staff's computers.

Comment: What about "_Our production of P.R. statements has expanded four times since we gave our head of P.R. a new smartphone and a new assistant_" ?

Comment: I like the way you think ogerard! :p

Comment: I agree.  I would go so far as to say *rate* is not an adjective that you would apply to procrastination at all.  I think you are really trying to say *amount* of procrastination.  And in @Martha's suggestion, procrastination implies amount, not rate.

Answer (score 3):

Our staff has achieved maximal velleity.

Comment: On a related note, what about pusilanimity ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the words are a proper fit for "rate of procrastination" but I'd suggest [slackness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slackness) and [sluggishness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sluggishness)

`slackness` has this idiom that fits

```
cut/give (someone) some slack
```

> To make an allowance for (someone), as
>   in **allowing more time** to finish
>   something

though in the case of procastinating, one gives oneself some slack

Comment: I like sluggishness: works get done but more slowly, activity is more diffuse and viscous. But I am afraid the original poster would like to have a more politically correct word at his disposal.

Answer (score 2):

I would modify the sentence rather than try to find a word that fits.  You don't really think about doubling the lack of something.  If anything, you might say, "The productivity has been halved since we gave them smart phones" since you can half productivity, but it's difficult to imagine doubling what would be the opposite of productivity.

Comment: "_You don't really think about doubling the lack of something_." I am afraid it is quite common. Think of debt, for instance

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with you.  Debt represents negative money, though it's still a quantity of money you're talking about.  If one person doesn't have it, another does.  So doubling your debt means the amount of money owed by you is doubled.  Procrastination is a concept which can't be measured by a number and therefore can't really be doubled without some context added.

Comment: you are right recalling procrastination is an _evasive_ notion by essence. If it is difficult to quantify, it does not make great sense to double or halve.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct antonym of "productivity" is "unproductivity."

That words sounds a little awkward to me however; another word is "idleness."

Comment: +1, the asker really seemed to be looking for antonyms of productivity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a state of "torpor" meaning near quiescent inactivity.

Our staff's torpor has doubled so far and looks to go even higher.

Comment: from Latin, from torpere ‘be numb or sluggish.’

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

> "Our staff's proclivity for cunctation has doubled since we gave them new smart phones."

Answer (score 0):

The word I might use is "tardiness."